# Lost the boot partition

Tags: windows-10, bios, windows-update, boot-partition

So hi, here is the problem:
I have windows 10 and pop os on my laptop, with dual boot. recently there was a problem with the third-party operating system selector that it wouldn't show and it directly booted up my windows and it was not a problem.

Tonight my windows have downloaded an update and I saw an optional update for my firmware (Bios) and downloaded it. when I restarted my device, both of the updates would start to operate Before the start of the windows. (pardon my poor English)
before I did the same with the Asus bios update software and I lost my windows boot partition, leading to a complete reinstall of windows.
This time I didn't think that the firmware update is the same Bios update and it would lead to the same situation.
Now when I boot up my laptop, It would bring a blue screen with the boot partition not found or something similar error. It is for windows, I mean it has a QR code and it says that the windows faced a problem and needs to restart, etc.
Now I'm using the pop os to ask for any possible solution to fix that partition without the need of reinstalling the whole windows.

Thank you So Much for your time, I appreciate any kind of help, and the sooner, the better.

Edit 1: The error is something similar to Inaccessible UEFI/boot partition

Comment: Are you booting with Grub?

Comment: @harrymc I don't think so, it's my laptops brand bootloader, ASUS

Comment: One way to fix boot issues is using disk imaging software. Some, such as Macrium Reflect, can try to fix the boot partition even if you've *not* yet made an image, but it is **far** better to work with a previously-made disk image.

Comment: @DrMoishe thanks for the help, but the windows won't boot up, no matter what I do

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm posting this answer from my windows 10 and here is what I did, hope it fixes your system as well :)

First of all, you have to somehow manage to boot into the safe mode.
in my case, the windows boot manager was a little weird and looked like the one in windows xp or seven. anyways, after entering the safe mode, the windows has been finally booted and on the screen was a text that said the update has been failed and we are undoing it.
that's it, wait until the end of the process, restart to exit the safe mode, and it should be as normal as before :)